# Powershell ShowUI add keyboard shortcuts to check boxes

Tags: wpf, powershell

I have a script right now where I make a bunch of checkboxes from a file list. I'd like to be able to use the arrow keys to sort through them (and toggle them as checked or not) so it'll be quicker than clicking.

```
$checkedFiles = StackPanel -ControlName 'Get-FilesToProcess' {                       
foreach($file in $files)
{
    New-CheckBox -Name $file ("Name" + $file)  -IsChecked true -On_GotKeyboardFocus     {$_.IsChecked = $false}

}          
New-Button "OK" -IsDefault  -On_Click { Get-ParentControl | Set-UIValue -PassThru |     Close-Control}      
} -show  

$checkedFiles
```

I'm a little green with WPF so I'm struggling through the events and methods. Am I on the right track with GotKeyboardFocus?

Comment: Hi Piers, not sure why you mention 'wpf' in your question - looks like just Powershell to me.

Comment: The Show-UI powershell module is built upon WPF. So really this is a question of how to make a keyboard navigable UI in WPF, I can figure out how to declare it in PS.

Comment: Yep, sorry, just looked it up - hadn't heard of it before!